# OpenGL : glRotatef not working?

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

the glRoatef function does not work I have no idea why...

Code Below This is the Display Function this is called in the main loop im using SDL as well:

```
void display(){

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

GLfloat ambientColor[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientColor);

Control(0.2,0.2,mousein);
drawSkybox(50.0);
UpdateCamera();

renderLine(0,0,0,100,0,0,0,0,255);
renderLine(0,0,0,0,100,0,0,255,0);
renderLine(0,0,0,0,0,100,255,0,0);
```

I forgot to add that this is the bit that is not working :

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(1,0,0,360);
glScalef(0.05,0.05,0.05);
glCallList(ship);
glPopMatrix();
```

---

```
for(int i = 0;i<planets.size();i++){
glPushMatrix();
planets[i].render();
glPopMatrix();
}
       }
```

In the Control Function these Rotations work.

glRotatef(-camPitch,1.0,0.0,0.0);
glRotatef(-camYaw,0.0,1.0,0.0);

Update Camera also translates the scene glTranslatef(-camX,-camY,-camZ);

Also in the init function this is how I set up the camera

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45,640.0/480.0,0.1,500.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: Define "is not working". The line `glRotatef(1,0,0,360);` is just multiplying an identity matrix and basically does nothing. What do you expect from a rotation of 360 degrees?

Comment: I was testing is it would even rotate it does not rotate by 360 in the program in increments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>void glRotatef(GLfloat  x,  GLfloat  y,  GLfloat  z, GLfloat  angle)</strike>

> void glRotatef(GLfloat  angle,  GLfloat  x,  GLfloat  y,  GLfloat  z);

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRotate.xml